# Create a div (or other element) that behaves simply as a container (no other functionality)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm looking to create an 'empty' container div that has the single purpose of **grouping child elements**. In other words, this container should have **no effect** on other elements in the page.

The reason I need such a container is for the purpose of grouping `React` elements without affecting page layout and styling.

```
const ReduxObservers = function(props)
{
    return (
        <EmptyContainer>
            <ReduxObserver1/>
            <ReduxObserver2/>
        </EmptyContainer>
    );
}

const AppContainer = function(props)
{
    return (
        <EmptyContainer>
            <App/>
            <ReduxObservers/>
        </EmptyContainer>
    );
}
```

Above is only a crude example, but it helps to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve.

- `<App>` represents a visible portion of our app (i.e it renders DOM elements).
- `<ReduxObserver>` represents an invisible portion of our app (i.e renders `null`)

`<AppContainer>` wraps those components (with the help of our `<EmptyContainer>`) and may be a child of `<body>` or some other element.

How can I design `<EmptyContainer>` such that it has no effect on layout/styling of its surrounding/child elements?

---

I had thought of having `<EmptyContainer>` 'clone' its parent element through `all: inherit;` however I foresee problems with this method (e.g cases where parent has padding or margin) which would not make it a true copy. Setting an additional `margin: 0px; padding: 0px;` might circumvent this issue, but I fear that other issues may arise.

---

Ideally, if there was a way to cascade styling and layout to the first 'non-empty' ancestor, that would be the best solution. For example, if we had a `<parent>` -> `<EmptyContainer>` -> `<child>` hierarchy.. If let's assume `<child>` had `width:100%; height:100%`, that it would calculate these properties and any other layout/styling from `<parent>`, ignoring `<EmptyContainer>` entirely. But I've haven't been able to find a way of doing this.

---

I also thought of setting the `<EmptyContainer>` div to `position:absolute;` so that it's layout would not affect it's children, but again this doesn't cover all cases.

---

And so I've turned to you in the hope that there might be some solution out there for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I believe you are trying to do this because React expects you to return a single element from the render method. If so, you don't need this as the requirement was deprecated in react 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `React` 16, you can use fragments, like this:

```
const AppContainer = function(props) {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <App/>
            <ReduxObservers/>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

As mentioned by @stojkosd in the comments, don't forget `import React, { Fragment } from 'react'`.

If you can't use `React` 16, there is a way to define a component that would act as a wrapper but won't render any markup. The component in this case is usually called `Aux` (from auxiliary) and it will just render its children passed as `props`. Here is what the component looks like:

```
const Aux = (props) => (props.children);
```

Then you can do:

```
const AppContainer = function(props) {
    return (
        <Aux>
            <App/>
            <ReduxObservers/>
        </Aux>
    );
}
```

Comment: `React.Fragment` returns `undefined` for me. But your `<Aux>` solution works wonders

Comment: import React, { Fragment } from 'react' and use fragment as component to wrap child components <Fragment> <App/> </Fragment>

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, if you are trying to do this because of the requirement that was there to return a single element from the render method, that is no longer required in React 16.

If not, you can use the following approaches (which are not based on React btw)

1. Use a `span` tag. `span` tag does nothing, just as a `div` except that the `div` tags display the children as a block, and span display inline.
2. Use the HTML5 `section` tag.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm using `react 16.0.0` with babel-jest. Upon compilation, I get an error that 'Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag.'

Comment: Yeah. You need to use fragments or simply return the elements as an array. See here, https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html